# "Invalid column name" error when using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a query I've been running quarterly that pulls data regarding patients with certain medical problems who visit a clinic. The query has been running fine, but I was just asked to add a gender field so we could filter patients by male and female and look at any resulting patterns. The demographics table I've been using for the rest of the patient data already has a gender column, so I simply added it to my query, but when I go to run it, I get an "Invalid Column Name" error and I don't know why.

Since I only need to display the Patient ID, Name, Visit Location, and now Gender, I've been using a subquery for the rest of the data I need to filter my patient list by. This is what I've got:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[MedHist: Patient ID] as [Patient ID],
[Patient: First Last Name] as [Patient Name],
[Patient: Gender] as [Gender],
ServiceLocationID as [Service Location]

FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
    mh.[MedHist: Patient ID],
    d.[Patient: First Last Name],
    d.[Patient: Date of Birth],
    d.[Patient: Gender] as [Gender],
    d.[Patient: Age],
    a.Status,
    mh.[MedHist: Procedure Code],
    pm.Description,
    v.ServiceLocationID

    FROM MedicalHistory mh INNER JOIN Demographics d ON mh.[MedHist: Patient ID] = d.[Patient: Patient ID]
        INNER JOIN Appointment a ON a.PatientID = d.[Patient: Patient ID]
        JOIN Visit v ON v.PatientID = d.[Patient: Patient ID]
        JOIN PatientMeds pm ON pm.PatientID = d.[Patient: Patient ID]

    WHERE d.[Patient: Age] ...is in a certain range
        AND a.Status ...is a certain thing
        AND pm.Description ...involves a certain medication
        AND some other stuff

    ) Demographics
```

As I mentioned, this query ran perfectly before I added the Gender field, and now I've got a red squiggle under the `[Patient: Gender]` portion of the initial `SELECT` statement and it's giving me the Invalid Column Name error. Any ideas why?

Comment: Does the inner query work by itself?  Does `Select count(1), [Patient: Gender] from demographics group by [Patient: Gender]` return 2 records?

Comment: Technically it returns 4 records since the system allows for "male," "female," "other," and "unknown," but otherwise, yeah, that worked.

Comment: Ok, so we know the column name is correct...  change the alias of the outer query to `oDemographics` perhaps aliasing it as the same name as an existing table is causing problems.  (and did the inner query itself work?)

Comment: so changing the alias of the outer query didn't help, and yes, the inner query by itself worked

Comment: Officially at a loss.  Only other thing I can think of is try is to alias inner query field `[Patient: Gender]` as something else and reference  the new alias on the outer...  if that works, I'd have no idea why though.

Comment: Hmm. Well, thanks for trying. It just seems so strange that everything worked perfectly before but that new field threw everything off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I'm answering my own question because I figured out the problem.

In my subquery, I have `d.[Patient: Gender] as [Gender]` in my `SELECT` statement (I typically rename columns like this because so many of the tables within this database have such long titles that it makes my columns unnecessarily wide and ugly). So then when I'm trying to select that same `[Patient: Gender]` field in my main query, the system can't find it because it's been renamed in the subquery. The following code works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [MedHist: Patient ID] as [Patient ID],
    [Patient: First Last Name] as [Patient Name],
    Gender,
    ServiceLocationID as [Service Location]

FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
    mh.[MedHist: Patient ID],
    d.[Patient: First Last Name],
    d.[Patient: Date of Birth],
    d.[Patient: Gender] as [Gender],
    d.[Patient: Age],
    a.Status,
    mh.[MedHist: Procedure Code],
    .....and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You may *think* the column is in the demographics table, but it is not.

The most likely reason (in this case) is a spelling mistake.  If I had to guess, there are additional spaces in the name, before or after 'Gender'.

One way to find the actual name of the column is to look in `information_schema.columns`:

```
select '|' + column_name + '|'
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'Demographics' and
      lower(column_name) like '%gender%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name the FROM table eg t1 you should name the column in select according withn this (dinamic) tablename

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
  [t1: Patient ID] as [Patient ID],
  [t1: First Last Name] as [Patient Name],
  [t1: Gender] as [Gender],
  [t1: ServiceLocationID as [Service Location]

  FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT
      mh.[MedHist: Patient ID],
      d.[Patient: First Last Name],
      d.[Patient: Date of Birth],
      d.[Patient: Gender],
      d.[Patient: Age],
      a.Status,
      mh.[MedHist: Procedure Code],
      pm.Description,
      v.ServiceLocationID

      FROM MedicalHistory mh INNER JOIN Demographics d ON mh.[MedHist: Patient ID] = d.[Patient: Patient ID]
          INNER JOIN Appointment a ON a.PatientID = d.[Patient: Patient ID]
          JOIN Visit v ON v.PatientID = d.[Patient: Patient ID]
          JOIN PatientMeds pm ON pm.PatientID = d.[Patient: Patient ID]

      WHERE d.[Patient: Age] ...is in a certain range
          AND a.Status ...is a certain thing
          AND pm.Description ...involves a certain medication
          AND some other stuff

      ) t1
```